Как декомпилировать .exe файл?
Писал проект на С# в VS 2022 и сохранилась не та версия, но при этом в папке проекта лежит exe файл этой программы, которая работает так как последняя версия кода. Возможно как то узнать или восстановить код, что бы не переписывать прогу?

возможные дубликаты

dotPeek ​

Целиком восстановить не удастся

Попробуй программы DnSpy (лучше этот вариант), или же IlSpy.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
